# UITextField text color transparent

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I want to set the color of my text in my UITextField. The textborder is black but the color on the inside is transparent. How do I add color to it?

Here is what I have:

```
let memeTextAttributes:[String:Any] = [
        NSStrokeColorAttributeName: UIColor.black,
        NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white,
        NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-CondensedBlack", size: 40)!,
        NSStrokeWidthAttributeName: 3.0]

topText.delegate = self
topText.defaultTextAttributes = memeTextAttributes
topText.text = "TOP"
topText.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
topText.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
topText.center.x = self.view.center.x
topText.center.y = self.view.frame.origin.y + 150
topText.minimumFontSize = 10
topText.textColor = UIColor.white
```

Comment: 1. Don't set both `defaultTextAttirbutes` and `textColor`. 2. The text field's background is white by default so your white filled text on a while background may make it appear to be transparent.

Comment: okay, i removed the textColor statements but that didn't help. Thanks, any other suggestions?

Comment: Did you read my 2nd point?

Comment: i did. there is an image behind the textfield UI elements. currently it looks like words with black border and transparent color

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to do an insane amount of research. Here is what i ended up with:

```
let memeTextAttributes:[String:Any] = [
        NSStrokeColorAttributeName: UIColor.black,
        NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white,
        NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-CondensedBlack", size: 40)!,
        NSStrokeWidthAttributeName: -5.0
    ]
```

`NSStrokeWidthAttributeName` had to be a NEGATIVE number/float to fill in the color, not a POSITIVE number/float! A positive float made the color transparent.

My project - https://github.com/ryanwaite28/ios-developer/blob/master/Meme%20Me/MemeMe2/MemeCreateEditController.swift

Took me the whole day.

Wowzerz...

Answer (score -1):

Sorry I misunderstood what you wanted. If you want the background to be transparent, the text border color to be black, and the text color to be white, you should 1) set the text field's `backgroundColor` property to `.clear`, 2) set the `borderColor` property of the text field's `layer` property to be `UIColor.black.cgColor`, 3) set the `borderWidth` property of the text field's `layer` property to be `1`, and 4) set the text field's `textColor` property to `.white`.

```
topText.backgroundColor = .clear
topText.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
topText.layer.borderWidth = 1
topText.textColor = .white
```

Comment: i want the background to be transparent, the text border color to be black, and the text color to be white. like how meme generators do it. this is for a project(Udacity ios developer nanodegree).

Comment: how do i set that in the dictionary?

Comment: How does this answer?